# Parse nested JSON as generic collection with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson, generic-collections

my json object starts with an object, then contains an array of the object I want `{ "myObjectArray":[ {....} , {....} , {....} ] }`, I have made the model file for the object represented in `{....}` , how do I get this generic collection code to not assume my root element is an array without making a new nested object file

This is what I currently have,

```
 Type listType = new TypeToken<List<T>>() {
                }.getType();
 List<T> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```

but this assumes that my json object is constructed like this `[{....}, {....}, {....}]` instead of the way I detailed above

Therefore, parsing returns a JsonSyntaxException

`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2`

Without creating a pointless model object that contains one variable `"myObjectArray"` which contains a List of `myObject` , how would I modify a GSON builder to accomodate?

(I am using android so I can't use a lot of the Oracle JVM reflection methods, including `ParameterizedTypeImpl`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder(); 
mGson = builder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
listType = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<T>>>() {}.getType();
parsedGSON = mGson.fromJson(reader, listType);
```

is the answer

GSON creates a LinkedTreeMap object